# Boost SQL Server priority: should it be used?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster

I'm trying to optimize my SQL Server 2008 instances on Windows cluster (on Windows Server 2008). I'm having several SQL Server instances on two cluster nodes. I was thinking that should I enable the "priority boost option" on every instance? What are the pros and cons of using this option in my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can let the core processes of the OS to starve for resources. It is suggested not to enable that option.

Comment: Agreed.  I've also seen cases where SQL Server's priority has exceeded the hardware manufacturer's driver priority, and the drivers haven't been able to get the CPU time they need to keep up with SQL Server.  Caused a bluescreen at StackOverflow, believe it or not.